# Cannot open database resquested by the login

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014

I have created a WCF Service in Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to create a connection of my service with SQL Server Management Studio 2014. I am getting the following error.

> Cannot open database "DatabaseName" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'admin'.

I tried the following solution from Youtube and other websites. But it didn't work for me.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/

My code is as follows:

```
 string sdwConnectionString = @"Data Source = DESKTOP-JSKR320; user id= admin; password= Password; Initial Catalog = DatabaseName;";

 try 
 {
     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sdwConnectionString);
     using (connection)
     {
         connection.Open();    
         using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
         {
             command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             for (int i=0; i<walls.Count; i++)
             {
                 command.CommandText = "addWall ";    
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("floorid", walls[i].floorid);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("x1",walls[i].x1);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("y1",walls[i].y1);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("x2",walls[i].x2);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("y2",walls[i].y2);
             }
             command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         added = true;
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
 }
```

Comment: seems you SQL Administrator is not added to SSMS for more details please go through   http://itproguru.com/expert/2014/09/how-to-fix-login-failed-for-user-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-step-by-step-add-sql-administrator-to-sql-management-studio/

Comment: @Ashu that article is completely irrelevant to this. 1) it's showing how to create a windows login, whereas the connectionstring above clearly uses a SQL login. 2) A C# application should **never** be given sysadmin rights (despite what the OP has decided to call their SQL login)

Comment: "I am trying to create a connection of my service with SQL Server Management Studio 2014" ...no, this code has nothing to do with SQL Server Management Studio. Your C# code is just another client of the SQL Server, the same as Management Studio. Management Studio and your C# code do not interact. Maybe you tried to use Management Studio to set up the user account...if so then it seems you didn't give the account permission to the specific database you're trying to open with this code. Or maybe you did it on the wrong database, or wrong server instance or something.

Comment: Side note: you should clear the parameter collection since you are in a loop.

Comment: @ADyson I have used the same code in some other WPF applications and it is working fine in that application. The database name, user credentials, data source name; everything is correct.

Comment: Ok but the error is telling you the exact opposite of that. It doesn't lie. Check and double check both the credentials and the connection details.